# Creating file/image folder directory for Spring MVC and Maven WebApplication

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I'm building a web app with Maven and Spring MVC.I've decided to save my images in a directory folder, not in database.I will save links of images to database. After searching I've found that saving images in the application directory or the directory of WAR file is bad practice when you have many images. Now my project has default maven directory:

```
--src
----main
------java
------resources
------webapp
---------WEB-INF
----test
```

Now my questions are:

1. Is it really a bad practice to save image in Application Directory?
2. If so, Then where should I put my image folder?inside the "src" or
   Outside "src" or inside "main"?

Comment: Yes it is, you shouldn't change your application while running (that is basically what you are doing when storing files there). Store them outside the application in any arbitrary directory. So neither src nor main nor anything related to your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I agree that is bad practice, your application directory can be erased during redeploy etc...
2. As already suggested by Deinum, store it somewhere else. And I will add part of my spring-boot app configuration that I use for serving such images by the application server:

   ```
   @Component
   class WebConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
       @Override
       public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("file://" + imageDir);
       }

   }
   ```

Just replace `imageDir` with proper path where do you store images.

Comment: WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is being shown as deprecated.